# Problem querying into object hierarchy with nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hierarchy, queryover

**Problem:**

I have the object hierarchy `A => B => C` - that's `A` references `B` and `B` references `C`.  `C` contains the `Name` property I'm trying to query on.  I am trying to call the following code to get the list of `A's`

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (A)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("B.C.Name", "Test"));
return criteria.List<A>();
```

I receive the error "Could not resolve property: B.C.Name of: A".  All of my mappings look good whereby `B` contains a `C` property and `C` contains a `Name` property.  I've also verified the mappings are correct because I'm running other queries that successfully retrieve the requested data.

Basically, I'm trying to get all the `A's` that match the name in `C`.  So how do I write a query that can do this?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QueryOver:

```
session.QueryOver<A>()
    .JoinQueryOver(a => a.B)
    .JoinQueryOver(b => b.C)
    .Where(c => c.Name == "Test")
    .List<A>();
```

You could also do it with aliases.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that did it.  I also found a good article on the QueryOver API at http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx.  Sometime you just need to know what things are called to get started in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the best info on QueryOver out there :)